# NameError in Python, name is not defined

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a script, such when debugmode = 1 you can break the script by pressing the "UP" key on the LCD.  On the other hand, when debugmode = 0 it goes back to the main menu.  However, I'm getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'debugmode' is not defined
```

This is where debugmode is set:

```
if lcd.buttonPressed(lcd.LEFT):
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message('Debug mode is enabled.')
    sleep(3)
    lcd.clear
    debugmode = 1
elif lcd.buttonPressed(lcd.RIGHT):
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message('Debug mode is disabled.')
    sleep(3)
    lcd.clear
    debugmode = 0
```

And this is where debugmode is called:

```
if debugmode == 1:
    break
else:
    subprocess.Popen("/home/fakepath/mainmenu.py")
    break
```

**UPDATE**: Ignacio's reply fixed my name error and kindall's comment fixed my problem with the variable not being set.  Thanks Ignacio and kindall!

Comment: Are you calling it before you set it?

Comment: Are you setting `debugmode` in a function, while it is a global variable? If so, you need a `global debugmode` in your function(s) that set it.

Comment: Kindall, that was the issue.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the name first, then rebind it after.

```
debugmode = 0
if lcd....
   ...
```

Comment: I've tried this, but when debugmode it set to 1 in the above script, it isn't recorded and for some reason the script still thinks that debugmode is equal to 0.

Comment: That is a completely different problem.

Comment: So why doesn't the script set the value of debugmode?

Comment: Because you've done something else wrong. But you've not shown what.